# openAssetFileDescriptor does not truncate OneDrive file

Tags: java, android, file-io, storage, onedrive

Using the following code, a text file that lives on Google Drive erases first as expected,leaving only the newly written content in the file. If the file lives on OneDrive the first x bytes are overwritten and the remaining original bytes left intact. Does anyone know of a work around for OneDrive files. I need the old contents erased and only the new content from the write to remain.

According to these docs 
[openAssetFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openAssetFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) and 
[openAssetFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openAssetFile(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal))
 that is what should happen.

I have tried this using Java/Android Studio and C#/Xamarin, Android phone 9 api 28.

```
public void saveFile(View view)
{
    try
    {
        AssetFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

        fileOutputStream.write(("Overwritten again " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n").getBytes());

        fileOutputStream.close();

        pfd.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor()` ?

Comment: Results were identical. Changed -- 
AssetFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");
-- to --
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");

Comment: Also tried (same result) - OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri, "w");
            outputStream.write(("Overwritten again " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n").getBytes());

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't come up with a why it doesn't work as documented, but I have come up with a work around to simulate expected behavior. Wouldn't mind comments if anyone sees a better way.

```
 public void saveFile(View view)
    {
        try
        {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

            //Added if-block to simulate automatic truncate when file located on onedrive.
            if( (fileUri.toString()).contains("skydrive"))
            {
                  FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
                  fileChannel.truncate(0);
            }

            fileOutputStream.write(("Overwritten again " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n").getBytes());

            fileOutputStream.close();

            pfd.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use following, just replace "w" with "rwt" to truncate the original file.

```
getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(fileUri, "rwt")
```